# How do I loop through a list of stock tickers in Matlab?

Tags: list, matlab, loops, for-loop, stocks

This is the current code I'm attempting to use in order to loop through a "list" of tickers to load the corresponding file. However, Matlab doesn't seem to like to accept separate strings. I'm not quite sure how Matlab functions yet. However, it is clear that it does not handle text as easily as Python.

```
    Stocks = {'JPM','KO','GOOG','PG'};
    for Stock = Stocks;
        stockData.(Stock) = load(Stock '.csv');
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid. I don't know what `stockData` is, and what you want to assign to it, but here's a loop that iterates through the cell array `Stocks` and loads each file in turn:

```
Stocks = {'JPM','KO','GOOG','PG'};
for i = 1:length(Stocks);
    load([Stocks{i}, '.csv'])
end
```

You can keep going from here.